# Why is this substitution involving the end of each line adding more to the beginning of the line?

Tags: regex, perl

I have some document into which I want to add something at the beginning and at the end of each line. The original document looks like this:

```
firstLine
secondline
```

I want to turn it into this:

```
put 'firstLine';
put 'secondline';
```

By using the following Perl script, I can only turn it into this:

```
put 'firstLine';
';put 'secondline';
```

It seems that there is a `$` at the end of the first line and at the beginning of the second line. Could someone help me to figure out what is wrong with the following Perl script?

```
use File::Find;
use strict;

my ($filename, @lines, $oldterm, $newterm);    #,$File::Find::name);
my $dir = ".";

open MYFILE, ">error.txt" or die $!;
find(\&edits, $dir);

sub edits() {
    $filename = $File::Find::name;
    if (grep(/\.txt$/, $filename)) {           #only process the perl files

        # open the file and read data
        # die with grace if it fails
        open(FILE, "<$filename") or die "Can't open $filename: $!\n";
        @lines = <FILE>;
        close FILE;

        # open same file for writing, reusing STDOUT
        open(STDOUT, ">$filename") or die "Can't open $filename: $!\n";

        # walk through lines, putting into $_, and substitute 2nd away
        for (@lines) {
            s/(&.+)/' "$1" '/ig;
            s/^/put '/ig;
            s/$/';/ig;
            print;
        }

        #Finish up
        close STDOUT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do it in one step you should have better luck. Something like:

```
s/^(&.+)$/put '$1';/im;
```

Answer (score 8):

don't use regular expressions at all: you already have the lines separated in the @lines array:

```
for ( @lines ) {
    chomp; # remove newline at the end of the implicit variable $_
    print "puts '$_'\n";
}
```